# collectd plugin dbi interval

Tags: intervals, dbi, collectd

I'm new in collectd and I'm currently testing some configuration to get metrics at work.

I'm using the dbi plugin to request information in mysql databases, so I set my queries and my database to get everything. My problem now it s to set 2 different interval between requests, one of my query have to request every 30 seconds and the other every 5 minutes.

I look for this information but I didn't find anything with dbi, anybody know how to set the interval for queries?

Best